# Celery "unregistered task" error only on Heroku

Tags: flask, heroku, celery

My Flask app with celery works well locally on Mac. But on Heroku, the celery worker raises the error `Received unregistered task of type 'app.task_func'.` I am sure that the same commit of Git has been pushed to Heroku. I googled and asked ChatGPT-4, but could not find out a solution.

Here is my Flask code:

```py
from celery import Celery
from celery.backends.base import DisabledBackend

def make_celery(app_name=__name__):
    app = Flask(app_name)
    app.config.update(
        CELERY_BROKER_URL=os.environ.get('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379'),
        CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=os.environ.get('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')
    )
    celery = Celery(app_name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)

    class ContextTask(celery.Task):
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return self.run(*args, **kwargs)

    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return app, celery

app, celery = make_celery()

@celery.task
def task_func(data):
    return heavy_process(data)
    
@app.route('/path', methods=['POST'])
def api_func():
    data = "test data"
    task = generate_assistant_response.delay(data)
    return jsonify({'message': "worker start", 'task_id': task.id}), 202
```

My Procfile looks like this

```
web: uwsgi --http 0.0.0.0:$PORT --chdir app --module app:app --master --processes 4 --threads 2
worker: celery -A app.app.celery worker --loglevel=DEBUG --concurrency 2
```

How do I fix the `Received unregistered task of type 'app.task_func'` error occurred only on Heroku?